# .launch files in maven or gradle

Tags: eclipse, maven, gradle

What is the "correct"/better place to put eclipse's .launch files in a maven/gradle project? I want to commit my run configurations but I don't know where to put the files

I know maven and gradle are always about standarization so I rather ask than put them in a random folder and then get in trouble with some plugin

After creating a launcher on each maven module now I have each launcher appearing twice in eclipse. This is due to the fact that when I check out my multi-module project it creates an eclipse project for the top POM as well as for each child POM and all the files are "duplicated" in the Navigator view, once for the top and once for each module. This to me means that either I have some problem in my maven organization or that I am putting the launcher in the wrong place

**Edit**
Since I asked this question I learned of a new way to solve this. Enable an experimental feature in eclipse which will prevent the subprojects to appear in the top project. The setting is under *windows/preferences/maven/**Hide folders of physically nested modules***

Comment: They are Eclipse files, not Maven files, so I'd leave them where Eclipse expects to find them. Running vanilla Maven (e.g. from the command line) should ignore these files, unless you expressly point some plugin at them.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue with duplicate launch configurations appearing. So the only work-around I see is putting the .launch files in the root project so that Eclipse only finds them once. Don't like that very much though...

Comment: What i ended up doing was creating a `launchers` folder in the root and putting them there. The only drawback is that if you have many modules and you want to check out only one or two, you lose the launchers

Comment: There is an old Eclipse bug about launches appearing twice -- https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=398523

Comment: @HDave this is caused only if you put the launcher in the child project, meaning the launcher files will be accessible both via the parent's project in the child subfolder and via the child project. A workaround is to close the parent (aggregator) project and only leave leaf projects open in your workspace. Another alternative is to move the launchers to the parent project so that they are available only via 1 path

Comment: @Hilikus - you are 100% correct, I just want to have my cake and eat it too, as (as you pointed out) moving them to the parent project means they are unavailable to developers just working on a single module.  Pick your poison I guess...

Comment: I has this very same problem with gradle 3.5 and Eclipse Oxygen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard location in Eclipse is in the project's root directory, that's where I always save them (and commit to SVN). Maven will ignore them there by default, so they will not show up in your artifacts.

One additional thing to keep in mind (since you mentioned that you want to commit the launch configurations to SCM and possibly share them with others): Avoid absolute paths in the launch configurations, since they will probably not work for other people. Try to use relative paths or Eclipse variables pointing to your local resources.

**Edit:** moved comment that answers the question

In this case you might consider moving them to a sub-directory (launch?). It should be one that is ignored by Maven by default (so not src/main/java or src/main/resources. On the other hand, I'm not sure whether Eclipse will pick up the files from a sub-directory... I've always kept them in the project root.

Comment: I noticed that too. The thing is I have like 4 or 5 launchers and I don't like the mess of having them in the root since I already have maven1 and maven3 files in it

Comment: In this case you might consider moving them to a sub-directory (launch?). It should be one that is ignored by Maven by default (so not `src/main/java` or `src/main/resources`. On the other hand, I'm not sure whether Eclipse will pick up the files from a sub-directory... I've always kept them in the project root.

Comment: IIRC eclipse will search the whole code tree looking for .launch. So you say that any other directory. I was worried that creating another directory in the root would confuse maven. Maven will just ignore it?

Comment: Usually yes, they should be ignored - every Maven plugin has its own standard directory, like `src/main/java` for the java-compiler-plugin. You shouldn't have any problems if you avoid the obvious ones.